# Date difference when group by value change

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          FILE       |     UNIT         |      DATE           |    ID SEQUENCE   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         34       |      01/02/2000     |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         34       |      01/05/2000     |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         40       |      01/05/2000     |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         40       |      01/02/2000     |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         40       |      01/02/2000     |         14       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         40       |      01/15/2000     |         15       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         34       |      01/16/2000     |         16       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         70       |      01/17/2000     |         17       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         70       |      01/28/2000     |         18       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I need to build a view like this (get the amount of days a file stay in every unit)

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|         FILE        |     UNIT         |    DAYS IN UNITY    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          10         |         34       |         3           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          10         |         40       |         10          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          10         |         34       |          1          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          10         |         70       |         11          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Any advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is DAYS IN UNITY calculated?

Comment: @ErgiNushi for example the first row in the desired view the days_unity is equal to the date difference between the record with id_sequence = 11 minus record with id_sequence = 10 (01/05/2000 - 01/03/2000)

Comment: But if it is a difference of dates between first and last row in group why is your third value in output `1`, not `0`? If it should be zero, then you can use [this query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4561f5b0ba82f0daddfc63769e7b0a22), if you want to add one for singleton then add one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  For this purpose, I am thinking difference of row numbers:

```
select file, unit, 
       (lead(min(date), 1, max(date)) over (partition by file, unit) -
        min(date)
       ) as days_in_unity
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by file order by id_sequence) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by file, unit order by id_sequence) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by file, unit, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  If you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference of the two row numbers is constant for the rows with the same `unit` value.

Comment: I need to keep the order of the units, no matter if a values is repeated, the field DAYS IN UNIT is the difference between dates when a file enter and exit a unit

Comment: @Joseleg . . . I was wondering how that was calculated.  It is just the difference of two dates, so I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but doesn't work as I needed. show 0 in days_in_unit and not in the right order. Thanks

Comment: @Joseleg . . . It would help if you explained the logic for the column in your question.  I have made another stab at guessing the logic you want.

Comment: I need to create a timeline of how many days a file is in a unit(department), for example using the first two (id_sequence = 10 , 11) records, the file enter into the department (unit 34) the 01/02/2000 and left the department(unit) the 01/05/2000. After the file go to the department(unit) 40

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of Oracle (12c and above), it may be an idea to use MATCH_RECOGNIZE (pattern matching).  In the following query, we define 2 patterns:

{1} multiple days, with a start date and an end date.  This pattern may contain "iffy" dates eg the 01/02/2000 in between 01/05/2000 and 01/15/2000 for unit 40.

{2} single day: this occurs when the "start" and "end" are on one and the same day.  In the MEASURES clause we pick up all the columns we need, and COALESCE them in the SELECT clause (MATCH_RECOGNIZE documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)).

**Table**

```
create table fileandunit( FILE_, UNIT, DATE_, ID_SEQUENCE )
as
select  10, 34, to_date( '02-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 10 from dual union all
select  10, 34, to_date( '05-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 11 from dual union all
select  10, 40, to_date( '05-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 12 from dual union all
select  10, 40, to_date( '02-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 13 from dual union all
select  10, 40, to_date( '02-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 14 from dual union all
select  10, 40, to_date( '15-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 15 from dual union all
select  10, 34, to_date( '16-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 16 from dual union all
select  10, 70, to_date( '17-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 17 from dual union all
select  10, 70, to_date( '28-JAN-2000', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 18 from dual ;
```

**Data and patterns**

```
select * from fileandunit order by id_sequence ;

  FILE_   UNIT DATE_         ID_SEQUENCE 
     10     34 02-JAN-00              10 --   start
     10     34 05-JAN-00              11 --   end
     10     40 05-JAN-00              12 -- start
     10     40 02-JAN-00              13 -- iffy
     10     40 02-JAN-00              14 -- iffy
     10     40 15-JAN-00              15 -- end
     10     34 16-JAN-00              16 --   single day
     10     70 17-JAN-00              17 -- start
     10     70 28-JAN-00              18 -- end
```

**Query**

```
select
  coalesce( RP.m_file, RP.s_file )         file_
, coalesce( RP.m_unit, RP.s_unit )         unit_
, coalesce( ( RP.m_end - RP.m_start ), 1 ) days_ 
from fileandunit
match_recognize(
  partition by file_ order by id_sequence
  measures
    enddt.file_    as m_file      -- m_: for multiple days
  , enddt.unit     as m_unit
  , startdt.date_  as m_start
  , enddt.date_    as m_end
  , singledt.file_ as s_file      -- s_: single day
  , singledt.unit  as s_unit
  , singledt.date_ as s_date
  one row per match
  pattern ( ( startdt iffydt* enddt ) | singledt )  -- multiple days (or) single day
  define
    startdt  as ( prev( date_ ) <= date_ or prev( date_ ) is null )
            and ( prev( unit ) <> unit  or prev( unit ) is null ) 
--
  , enddt    as ( next( date_ ) >= date_ or next( date_ ) is null )
            and ( next( unit ) <> unit  or next( unit ) is null )
-- 
  , iffydt   as ( prev( date_ ) >= date_ )  -- detect incorrect dates inside a multiple day block
            and ( prev( unit ) = unit )
--
  , singledt as ( prev( date_ ) = date_ - 1 and next( date_ ) = date_ + 1 )
            and ( prev( unit ) <> unit and next( unit ) <> unit ) 
) RP ;
```

**Result**

```
  FILE_   UNIT_   DAYS_ 
     10      34       3 
     10      40      10 
     10      34       1 
     10      70      11
```

Tested with Oracle 18c.  DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b72b0d2a3ea87d0f65781ce77c12260f).